# Generate resource usage time phased data in MS Project with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

I've been having an issue when populating the Resource Usage View of MS Project from a Windows Forms application in VB.Net (made with Visual Studio Community 2019), and I'd like to ask advice from someone with more experience than me, since I don't seen to be getting anywhere on my own.

The code is rather extensive, so I'll try to cut it down to the conflictive line (will be glad to show more if it's not enough):

```
projAssig.TimeScaleData(StartDate:=startDate, EndDate:=endDate, Type:=MSProject.PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, TimeScaleUnit:=MSProject.PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleHours).Item(1).Value = CStr(workHours)
```

This line is within a For loop, where I'm looping through all the assignments of a certain resource in order to populate them with data. "projAssig" is such assignment. Both "startDate" and "endDate" are Date variables, and "workHours" is a Single variable.

The idea is to assign the "workHours" amount of hours between the "startDate" and the "endDate". These three variables come from other parts of the code, and I can make sure their values are coherent.

The issue I have is that the line of code sometimes fails with this exception error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'El valor del argumento no es válido.'

The message is in spanish, but it basically says that one of the arguments has an invalid value. Doesn't specify which one.

Take note of the following examples:

startDate = #9/25/2019 06:00:00 PM#, endDate = #9/25/2019 10:00:00 PM#, workHours = 4 || Works without issues.

startDate = #9/25/2019 10:00:00 PM#, endDate = #9/26/2019 06:00:00 AM#, workHours = 8 || Fails with the above exception.

startDate = #9/25/2019 10:00:00 PM#, endDate = #9/25/2019 11:00:00 PM#, workHours = 1 || Fails with the above exception.

As I mentioned above, it says that one of the arguments has an invalid value, but if I look at the whole statement in the inspection window, it displays a string value of "" (and not an exception or error message as I would expect, given the message above).

I don't know if I'm just being oblivious, and this is simpler than it looks but I'm just not seeing it. Or maybe I'm not understanding how to actually use the TimeScaleData method. This whole issue just looks confusing to me.

I'll appreciate any help you are able to provide. Thanks for your time and your attention.

Kind Regards

Comment: `startDate = #9/25/2019 10:00:00 PM#, endDate = #9/25/2019 06:00:00 AM#,` looks wrong. It can't possible start at 10PM and end at 6AM of the same day.

Comment: My bad, endDate = #9/26/2019 06:00:00 AM#, edited the question. It's indeed the next day, didn't notice the mistake when writing the post. Just to clarify, the data is correct (set to finish the next day) when the code runs, and it still fails.